# Why whitelist in .htaccess still returns 'forbidden'?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 18.04.
I'd like to create whitelist of files accessible for users. (I saw two topics here, but it's not helping me)
I tried simply add in .httaccess

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    <Files "index.html">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

But it's not working, i've tried also many other configuration but still the answe is ''Forbidden'.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)!

Answer (score 0):

Come one. Stop using this `order allow,deny` unless you are using an older version of Apache.
 Apache themselves have mentioned:

> The directives provided by ]mod_access_compat](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html) have been deprecated by [mod_authz_host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html). Mixing old directives like Order, Allow or Deny with new ones like Require is technically possible but discouraged. This module was created to support configurations containing only old directives to facilitate the 2.4 upgrade. Please check the upgrading guide for more information.

Try using the new way of doing it:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Require all denied
<Files "index.html">
    Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Make sure you enable [mod_authz_host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html), and [mod_authz_core](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html), or it won't work.

Comment: ```
Considering dependency authz_core for authz_host:
Module authz_core already enabled
Module authz_host already enabled
```
but now server gives me 500

Comment: @PawełZając, remember to put the following inside httpd.conf only. You might've put it inside .htaccess.

Comment: Now it works, i neeed also type <ip-address>/index.html
So i tried to add `RedirectPermanent / http://192.168.1.212/index.html` to my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/00-default.conf` but i've gut Page Error: redirect to many times
Now it looks like this:
```
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        DirectoryIndex index.html
```
And 192.168.1.212 is again Forbiden...How should i redirect traffic to allow access only to my /var/www/html/index.html?